# Finished Basement - Framing Exterior Walls

Tags: framing, basement-refinishing

EDIT: Adding photos, changing tags[image: Basement wall. Studs behind the wrap.]

Complete newbie here, so I apologize if this question is lacking in detail. 
I am starting to do some research on finishing my basement - I've never framed anything previously.  My house was newly built and we moved in in Dec 2017.  My foundation is poured concrete.  All of the exterior walls are framed, insulated and then wall wrapped.

My question is - would I need to frame walls inside this existing framing / insulation / wall wrap OR could I just hang sheetrock along the framing already in place?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: A picture would help, but it certainly sounds like you could hang sheetrock or tile backer board and be done. Perhaps you can inquire of the builder, if you bought it newly built that recently.

Comment: What do you meany by "wall wrapped"? Especially on the *inside*? That doesn't sound good, especially if you have air conditioning....

Comment: Like Ecneral said - hang the sheetrock on the framing that's already there.  Assuming of course that the framing (I assume we're talking about 2x4's here?) is properly attached top & bottom (or to the wall).  If you do that, you want to make sure that you don't have any insulation bunched up on top of the studs that would cause the sheetrock to bow.